# PostgreSQL logical replication stacks with error 'could not receive data from WAL stream: server closed the connection unexpectedly'

Tags: postgresql, wal

I have logical replication established between 2 PostgreSQL servers (PostgreSQL 10.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit) on AWS rd

After adding some bunch of data to master server data could not be updated on 
replica side, replication lag grew up to few Gb size.

Tried to increase value of wal_sender_timeout to 300000

script to check replication slot lag

```
SELECT pg_replication_slots.slot_name,
    pg_wal_lsn_diff(pg_current_wal_lsn(), pg_replication_slots.restart_lsn) AS replicationslotlag,
    pg_replication_slots.active,
    pg_replication_slots.database,
    pg_replication_slots.active_pid
   FROM pg_replication_slots
```

Drop and recreate subscription helped, but looking for less costly solution

Comment: You'd have to read the logs on both primary and standby carefully to figure out the cause. Without the logs we cannot help you.

Comment: Log info on replica side containing:
ERROR: could not receive data from WAL stream: server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.

And nothing meaningful on publication side

Comment: Ok, and the other side?

Comment: I saw nothing concerning to replication. Few errors like duplicate key values while insert

Comment: Perhaps a firewall problem.

Comment: But, after drop and recreate subscription with the same parameters everything works fine without firewall settings changes

Comment: I don't know. Normally, when the one side says that the connection was closed unexpectedly, the other side should have something to say as well.

Comment: I observed the same with PG15.1. After dropping and recreating the SUBSCRIPTION unchanged, it worked?!